# Getting request data as stream and uploading it to the server in php

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am creating the backend API (in lumen) for an android application where the user will upload n number of images and videos.
The data will be sent in chunked (bytes) format.
The images will be iterated over and sent as ByteStream ( in Java ). How do I receive the streamed byte data from the request and successfully store it.

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` maybe?  Only thing I can think of.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix as I will be getting multiple streamed data, meaning an array of streams will it create a problem ?.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using php://input stream to get the input data (in bytes),
and file:// stream to write the data.
below is the example code.

```
$inputStream = fopen(php://input, 'rb');
$writableStream = fopen(file://filepath_here,'wb');
stream_copy_to_stream($inputStream, $writableStream);
fclose($inputStream);
fclose($writableStream);
```